# How to remove unwanted ticks from histogram and place ticks in dead centre

Tags: python, dataframe, histogram, xticks

I'm fairly new to the concept of binning and histograms and am having the following issue:

I want integer ticks to fall in the centre of my histogram bins. The values would need to be rounded, hence np.round in my code. I'll attach the relevant code and the output:
[snip of axis](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wc2gq.png) [works but not in center](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A1wXy.png)

I have tried this, which works in terms of putting the integer inside the centre of the bins, but I also see many other labels

[tried but too many ticks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kTSyF.png)

Comment: post the code and not the pictures of code.
Users need to be able to replicate the problem quickly, 
which text allows for (and pictures do not).
[how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)